# How can I make two vertical DIVs be the same length?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="left">xx</div>
  <div id="right">yy
    aa
    <br>
    <br>    
    <br>  
    aa
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#body { background-color: yellow; }
#left, #right { float: left; }
#left { background-color: blue; }
#right { background-color: red; }
```

What I need is for the DIV on the left to grow to be the same length as the one on the right? Is this possible? I tried a few things but it doesn't work.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGVMZ/)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous way to try it.  You didn't assign either of them a `height` so they won't be doing much at the moment.  If you add equal heights, they can be the same.  You can try `style="height:100%;"` for both of them

Or add that to those IDs in your CSS, or make a class with it and assign that to your divs.

Comment: I can't assign a height as it's variable and depends on the content.

Comment: if the content's size doesn't match then, the div's won't match either.

Comment: Yeah but I would like the background color to go to the bottom. That's part of the requirements!

Answer (score 0):

something like this $("#right").css("height", $("#left").css("height"));

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way about it, using display: table-cell

Won't work in older browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrGBB/

Answer (score 0):

You could having the right inside the left as so

```
<div class="left">
aa
   <div class="right">
     bb
     <br/>
     <br/>
     bb
   </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

and floating the right div right and stoppnig the left colapsing using the clear:both

Answer (score 0):

There's no real simple one line of code way to do this but there are many solutions out on the web like [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) or [Equal Height Columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Give it a Google and find a solution that works best for you.